# Authentication (and Authorization) in an app that's not fully a SPA - Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, authorization, laravel-passport

Hi I'm building an app with Larval and vue.js. This app is not a fully single page application but is a combination of **vue and blade**.

For example, the dashboard or login page and some other pages are **SPA-based** and are fully implemented with vue. But the landing page and some other pages have been created by **blades** that may have used vue components in some of them.

My question is about **authentication** in such cases. Is **laravel passport** appropriate for such cases? Or should I use jwt or something else? Because I need authentication on both types of pages (Vue-based, Blade-based). And it's done on almost every page.

On the other hand, I used **laravel-permission - Spatie** to control permissions and roles. Is it possible for passports to define **roles and permissions** and control based on them? I mean displaying or hiding elements and links, accessing certain sections, or doing some work with permissions checking.

What resources do you offer to start learning how to develop **authentication and authorization** in such apps?

**Edit:**

Maybe there was some ambiguity in my question, so I'll explain a little more. Suppose our website has three parts:

1. The first part that includes landing page, display of a post, display of all posts and more. This section is implemented by **blade** and may also use vue components.
2. The second part is the **user profile page** of the site where users can edit their own information, view their posts and edit them, view registered comments and more. This section is **SPA** and is fully implemented with Vue and only logged in users can see it.
3. The third part is the **admin dashboard page**, which is needed to manage different sections, apply settings and more. This section is also **SPA** and fully implemented with Vue. In this section, only users with the **Administrator role** are allowed, and each one can perform certain tasks based on the **permissions** given to them. This means, it must be checked whether the user is allowed to see a section or perform a specific task, or not.

**Routing** is also performed by vue on the user profile and admin dashboard pages, and actions are performed by axios and sending requests to apis written in laravel. And all three parts are in the **same application**.

So the question is, how should **Authentication and Authorization** be done in this scenario? Is laravel-passport appropriate for this task? Is it possible to do both in laravel-passport? For example, Authorization is going to be done in the front-end section by vue, how should this be done? Is it possible to combine **laravel-passport and laravel-permission - Spatie**? Or do we need it at all? Perhaps the more general question: Is this scenario reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the intermediate approach, blade login/register and the Laravel passport middleware https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript.

> This Passport middleware will attach a laravel_token cookie to your outgoing responses. This cookie contains an encrypted JWT that Passport will use to authenticate API requests from your JavaScript application. Now, you may make requests to your application's API without explicitly passing an access token

Spatie permission is great for managing permissions and roles. You can protect your api routes with [middleware](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/middleware/) or checks in your controller.

Answer (score -1):

You making it too complicated. if you are calling your vue components in blade file you don't need passport at all but if your front end is separate from back end then you need to use passport because you don't have access to session...

> On the other hand, I used laravel-permission - Spatie to control permissions and roles. Is it possible for passports to define roles and permissions and control based on them?

Passport doesn't care what kinda permission and role system you want to use you can use anything that you want